# QT 5.2.0 - Cannot add commands to previously defined target

Tags: qt, target, defined

I have this problem while Building project:

```
17:49:24: Running steps for project SceneVisualizer...
17:49:24: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
17:49:24: Starting: "D:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    D:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
Cannot add commands to previously defined target debug\moc_previewwindow.cpp.
Cannot add commands to previously defined target debug\moc_visualizerwindow.cpp.
17:49:24: The process "D:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
17:49:24: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

When i chose to run project from QT:

```
Starting D:\filipbp\Projekty, zdrojove kody\build-SceneVisualizer-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MSVC2010_32bit_OpenGL-Debug\debug\SceneVisualizer.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
D:\filipbp\Projekty, zdrojove kody\build-SceneVisualizer-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MSVC2010_32bit_OpenGL-Debug\debug\SceneVisualizer.exe crashed
```

When I run .exe from outside, it starts correctly, but if I chose to load prepared scene, the program crashes.

I don't know what to do with it, please help.

Comment: where is the code?, the project you are using a template?

Comment: What part of code ?  ...i have to edit existing code for school project, but i am not abe to compile it sucesfully.  I have not errors there, just only this Cannot add commands to previously defined target debug\moc_previewwindow.cpp.    and 
Cannot add commands to previously defined target debug\moc_visualizerwindow.cpp.      in compile Output

Comment: Please show the contents of the .pro file.

Comment: it was too long to copy there, ...http://pastebin.com/zPXuPedQ

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem. In my case it happened because I added twice the same file in .pro